# Save MS Dynamics CRM Records as PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas, dynamics-crm-2016

Recently, I had been asked by a client that they require to download all CRM Records of all entity as PDF.

I tried with html2canvas and jspdf libraries , but i was not able to download the form completely(form was scroll-able), It gave me only what i was able to currently see, not the remaining scrollable part.

Please guide me if i am doing something wrong in the below code or there is any other way to do so.

```
function createPDF() {
    var a4 = [595.28, 841.89];

        var div = $('#HeaderTilesWrapperLayoutElement', window.parent.document);

        var xxxx = $($(div.context).find('iframe')[0]).contents().find("body");

        var xxx = xxxx.find("#tdAreas");
        var cache_width = xxx.width();

        $('body').scrollTop(0);
        getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {
            var
             img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
             doc = new jsPDF({
                 unit: 'px',
                 format: 'a4'
             });
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
            doc.save('techumber-html-to-pdf.pdf');
             xxx.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');
        });
    }

    // create canvas object
    function getCanvas() {
        xxx.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');
        return html2canvas(xxx, {
            imageTimeout: 2000,
            removeContainer: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: Most modern browsers and computers have the ability to print to PDF....if you haven't considered it already, maybe you could use CRM's print function and then choose "Save to PDF" as your printer?

Comment: Hi, i tried that also, but it was also able to print only first page.

Comment: Rather than a code-first solution, could you do this as a report?

Comment: Can provide some more detail on why the customer wants this functionality?